# How to download artifact/release-asset in another workflow

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible for Github actions to upload a build artifact for commits on a release branch, and then for another workflow to download & use that artifact?

```yaml
name: Deploy release to UAT & archive artifact
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
jobs:
  package:
    name: package and archive
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12'
      - name: serverless package
        uses: serverless/github-action@master
        with:
          args: package --stage=prod
      - name: Upload Release Asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ github.event.release.upload_url }}
          asset_path: .serverless
          asset_name: release-asset-${{ github.event.release.name }}.zip
          asset_content_type: application/zip
      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: release-artifact-${{ github.event.release.name }}
          path: .serverless
```

...but how do you download the asset/artifact?  I think `up/download-artifact` is intended only to be used only from the same workflow, and there doesn't seem to be an action for downloading a release asset.

```yaml
name: Deploy to production
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      release:
        description: Name of release to deploy
        required: true
        default: v1.0.0

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12'
    - run: npm ci --only=prod
    - name: Download the release artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: release-${{ github.event.inputs.release }}
        path: .serverless
    - name: serverless deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@master
      with:
        args: deploy --stage=prod --package=.serverless
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Comment: This question is ambiguous since it doesn't maintain a clear distinction between workflow artifacts and release assets.  The example creates both, the title mentions both "artifact" and "asset", and as a result, answers are inconsistent as to which scenario they solve.  Your use case may be able to use them interchangeably, but others will have a requirement of only one or the other.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`download-workflow-artifact` action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-workflow-artifact).

Answer (score 6):

One of my team mates got this working:

```yaml
      - id: download-release-asset
        name: Download release asset
        uses: dsaltares/fetch-gh-release-asset@master
        with:
          version: tags/${{ env.RELEASE }}
          file: myproject-${{ env.RELEASE }}.tar.gz
          target: release.tar.gz
          token: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Note that this only works on Linux, not on Windows.

Comment: It now works on Linux, Windows and MacOS.

Comment: @DavidSaltares - all the releases from 0.0.6 to date say, "This action only supports Linux runners as this is a docker container action." Presumably there's no chance using it with a self-hosted Windows instance (that does not have Docker installed)?

Comment: @RobPomeroy, apologies, I just removed the notice from the README.md https://github.com/dsaltares/fetch-gh-release-asset/commit/5d24fa77c1ae2e1e1dea54677d267f127d5de53a.

The action only requires node to be installed now. Should run on all 3 runner platforms.

Answer (score 5):

### Using a 3rd party GitHub Action

I needed to access another workflow's artifacts as well and was able to by using the [download workflow artifact](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-workflow-artifact) GitHub action.

In my case, I have separate `build` and `deploy` workflows and I needed to access the build artifacts from the deploy workflow. This is how I accomplished it:

```yaml
name: deploy

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [build]
    types: [completed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  deploy:
    # Only run the deployment if the build workflow succeeded.
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download build artifact from triggered workflow
        uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
        with:
          run_id: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
          name: BuildArtifact
          path: ./artifacts
          search_artifacts: true
```

The deploy workflow automatically runs when the build workflow completes on the `main` branch, and we get the build workflow's run ID using `github.event.workflow_run.id`.

### Using the GitHub API

If you do not want to use a 3rd party GitHub action and prefer to use the native GitHub API instead, [the GitHub Docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#using-data-from-the-triggering-workflow) show how to accomplish this same task.

Workflow to upload the artifact:

```yaml
name: Upload data

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Save PR number
        env:
          PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}
        run: |
          mkdir -p ./pr
          echo $PR_NUMBER > ./pr/pr_number
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: pr_number
          path: pr/
```

Workflow to download the artifact:

```yaml
name: Use the data

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Upload data]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  download:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Download artifact'
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            let allArtifacts = await github.rest.actions.listWorkflowRunArtifacts({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               run_id: context.payload.workflow_run.id,
            });
            let matchArtifact = allArtifacts.data.artifacts.filter((artifact) => {
              return artifact.name == "pr_number"
            })[0];
            let download = await github.rest.actions.downloadArtifact({
               owner: context.repo.owner,
               repo: context.repo.repo,
               artifact_id: matchArtifact.id,
               archive_format: 'zip',
            });
            let fs = require('fs');
            fs.writeFileSync(`${process.env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/pr_number.zip`, Buffer.from(download.data));

      - name: 'Unzip artifact'
        run: unzip pr_number.zip

      - name: 'Comment on PR'
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            let fs = require('fs');
            let issue_number = Number(fs.readFileSync('./pr_number'));
            await github.rest.issues.createComment({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              issue_number: issue_number,
              body: 'Thank you for the PR!'
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this quite easy these days using the API as described here:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-workflow

All you need to do once the action is created is set the "workflow" permission on your access token.

Here is an example yml. Set OTHER_REPO to be your user and repo name and the WF_NAME is the yml action file and also set the ARTIFACT_NAME

```
name: Download Built Artifact
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out Download Artifact 
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  download:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: "Download artifact"
      run: |
        OTHER_REPO="USER/REPO"
        WF_NAME="action-file.yml"
        ARTIFACT_NAME="test_artifact"
        RUN_ID=`gh run --repo ${OTHER_REPO} list --workflow ${WF_NAME} --json databaseId --jq .[0].databaseId`
        gh run --repo ${OTHER_REPO} download ${RUN_ID} -n ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
        # List the artifiact directory/files
        ls -lR
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACT_DEPLOY_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, however I had to use the personal access token with adequate access permissions for a GITHUB_TOKEN

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Marcin Kłopotek, I get it done finally.

Here's one simple example(add to github workflow `steps` section as you need):

```yaml
      - name: Download artifact
        id: download-artifact
        uses: dawidd6/action-download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: production-files
          repo: {repo_with_username, e.g. xxx/yyy}
          workflow: {the other workflow filename e.g. build.yml}
          path: {path you desired to extract to e.g. ./static/}
          search_artifacts: true
```

Answer (score 1):

actions/download-artifact v4 now supports that.
You can check the documentation here https://github.com/actions/download-artifact?tab=readme-ov-file#download-artifacts-from-other-workflow-runs-or-repositories

You have to supply a PAT with the correct permissions