# How to get artifact from a commit

Tags: github-actions

I want to have two github actions,

- one gets triggered when I commit, `commit.yml` and,
- another only when I tag the commit, `release.yml`.

The idea is when I commit, I will build artifacts. Then I will download the artifact and test locally. If everything goes fine, I'll tag. When I tag, I like to reuse the artifacts built with commit (instead of rebuilding them again) and publish those as release asset.

How do I pass the artifacts between runs using the same commit?

Comment: you could push your tested and taggued version on a release branch and then having your release.yml actions triggered 'on push on release branch.'

Comment: @boly38 I am not sure that would solve my problem. Building artifact for my project is taking long time (many hours). I don't want to trigger another build, just want to reuse. Are you suggesting pushing just the artifacts to another branch (namely release branch)?

Comment: Where are you publishing the artifacts? If it's docker for e.g you could include the commit SHA in the image version and pull it from the registry during the release run?

Comment: @spinlok the artifacts are uploaded using actions/upload-artifact@v2, I want to use this artifact in the release run if possible. Please elaborate more on your docker suggestion.

Comment: could you use the REST API to download the artifact from the release workflow? You'll need the `run-id` of the workflow run that generated the artifact. If that's always the most recent one, then you could get that using the REST API as well - https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository

Comment: @spinlok many thanks, I think this could work, let me give this a try.

Comment: @kibudude actually there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868918/how-to-download-artifact-release-asset-in-another-workflow?rq=1) and the recommendation is to use https://github.com/marketplace/actions/download-workflow-artifact . This should do the trick for you.

Comment: @spinlok yes it does, thank you so very much.