# GitHub Actions: Downloading release files from a different repository

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I have Repo A (private, in an organization), which has a GitHub Actions workflow that builds and bundles my application into a `tar.gz` file and includes it as an artifact in a Release.

I have Repo B (also private, same organization) which, in the GitHub Actions workflow, needs to download the release artifacts from a specific release of Repo A, and do other things with it.

What is the modern best-practices approach to enabling this cross-repo release access within an organization? Last time I did this, we had to use a Personal Access Token for a machine user that we created, which is all sorts of bad (machine user GitHub account, long-lived secret, etc.). GitHub has since added a lot of capability with the built-in `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret, with OIDC support within Actions, etc. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can store Github APP private key
and `APP_ID` as a variable for the repo.

Then use `actions/create-github-app-token@v1` to create an installation token.

Then you can use generated token in a step. Inside the step you can use for example gh cli.

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
    id: generate_token
    with:
      app-id: ${{ vars.APP_ID }}
      private-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
      owner: ${{ github.repository_owner }}

  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Download asset
    uses: ./.github/actions/download
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ steps.generate_token.outputs.token }}.
```

The app should be authorized to access repo with the asset

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [Linux Docker container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#types-of-actions), you can try and use [`dsaltares/fetch-gh-release-asset`](https://github.com/dsaltares/fetch-gh-release-asset) which is meant to:

> downloads an asset from a GitHub release and provides some release details as output.
> Private repos are supported.

You can find an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66451414/6309).
But it does use a GitHub token which defaults to `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`: make sure it is a [GitHub App installation access token](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication).

Comment: For cross-repo access, the token that I provide to this Action (which would be running in a job on Repo B) would have to be the token of an app installation on Repo A, since it's trying to download release files from Repo A, correct?

In that case, you would still need to store the token as a secret on Repo B, and long-lived secrets are something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Jordan Then (not tested), an action like `use-app-token` might help.